# How to work with strings in M2

Tags: magento2, core, character-encoding, utf-8

I want to use string functions and do not depend on severs configuration in terms of [overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php) and default char-set.

Say,  when I call `strtoupper($param)` it should be `mb_strtoupper($param, 'UTF-8')` in many cases.

This is definitely the framework responsibility.
But I can't find the right wrapper in M2.

There are some functions in 
`\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string`
but not all.

M2 core code sometimes calls **mb_**
`\vendor\magento\module-dhl\Model\Carrier.php`
`\vendor\magento\module-catalog-import-export\Model\Import\Product.php`
sometimes **iconv_**
`\vendor\magento\module-paypal\Model\Report\Settlement.php`

What is the right and recommended approach?

Comment: welcome back Amasty. why you have my edit :). you do not like this edit?

Comment: is this `sting functions` or `string function`?

Comment: Hi Amit, thank you for the note, fixed it :)  Do you know something about strings logic in M2?

Comment: i do have good idea on topics

Answer (score 2):

Thats definitely an interesting question.

So here's the thing: the `mb_string` library is a [requirement of Magento 2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html) (and as a side note the `iconv` library is also a requirement if you run PHP7)

So you won't be able to install M2 without it.

Thus Magento code don't care much about checking if `mb_` methods exist or not.

It seems like most of the time direct calls to the PHP methods are done without using a Magento string class for example:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager.php#L56
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/Config/Converter.php#L41
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/WordsFinder.php#L271

The only exception I found is this one I'm not too sure if it's relevant though: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/app/code/Magento/GoogleAdwords/Model/Filter/UppercaseTitle.php#L20

So I reckon you should be able to use those methods directly like Magento does.

Regarding the `iconv` methods I find it disturbing indeed. Some code checks if the library is implemented some other code simply use the `@` operator to mute the errors (which is not great right ?) so I'm not sure about those.

Comment: Thank you for the sharing the ideas. What is the best place, to your opinion, to set default encoding?  In magento 1 I see numerous cases in support request when we had to use  mb_strtoupper($param, 'UTF-8')  instead of just mb_strtoupper($param).   Or should we use mb_internal_encoding on app launch?

Comment: @Amasty honestly I'm surprised m2 does not handle that properly out of the box I feel like this is a bug. Did you try submitting an issue on github ?

Comment: May be we need to submit it, but I prefer to have some ready to use solution, as our clients can not wait )